# How do I resolve error when I run 'npm start' with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, create-react-app, postcss

I cloned a react project, after installing the packages and I run "npm start" it displays the error below.
It's not my code, I am to continue with the project but with the error I can't proceed.
Below is the error message

```
$ npm start
```

> zentsify@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:544
throw e;
^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\emman\Desktop\zenstify\zenstify2\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:361:10)
at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:697:9)
at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:538:36)
at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:607:31)
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1025:27)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\emman\Desktop\zenstify\zenstify2\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.13.0

I have tried uninstalling postcss and reinstalling it again

Answer (score 1):

try
1.)deleting your node_modules then reinstall everything
Or
2.) install that specific package using the --legacy-peer-deps or install all the packages at once with --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running `npm update`. Running `npm update` will update the installed modules that have issues with versioning. Once done, also run `npm audit fix --force`

I have faced this issue before in my environments and running `npm update` has helped.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mukul.
it still gave the below after running npm update and npm audit fix --force

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit request to https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org     
undefined
npm ERR! audit endpoint returned an error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by creating a .npmrc file and pasted the code below in it.
Make sure the .npmrc file is in the root directory of your project.

```
node-options="--openssl-legacy-provider"
```